# LENOVO S20-00 keyboard and mouse do not work

Tags: keyboard, lenovo

During installation and after reboot keyboard and mouse are working, but after file check numpad led is off and keyboard and mouse is not working anymore. It seems like no driver for USB? Ubuntu is latest one 20.04.4 for 64 bit desktop.

Comment: Did you try to unplug and plug the devices back in?

Comment: several times.  different usb socket too.  reinstall ubuntu 3x.  install Linux cinnamon MINT and it works. so hardware is good.